# JS file work only in index page

Tags: php, functions, javascript

i load my js files in functions file of the WP but it seems that the script only called in the index page and for other pages it doesnt work..

here is my code in functions file:

```
function loadjs() {

  wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom/js/script.js', '', 1, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('customjs');

  $translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
  wp_localize_script('customjs', 'object_name', $translation_array);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
```

please help :)

Comment: How are you testing that the script is loaded? Is it possible that it does load on other pages but there is a problem with the javascript? Have you looked at your browsers console in the developer tools for errors?

Comment: @TomJNowell I dont know why i didnt think of it.. you right! thanks:)